# Concentration of a bounded random variable, with monotonically decreasing PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, concentration-of-measure

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable bounded by $X\le C^2$ and mean $\mathbb{E} X = C$ for some constant $C>1$. Moreover, we know that its PDF is monotonically decreasing in the $[0, C^2]$. Can we upper bound $P(X>\varepsilon C)$, with a quantity that only depends on $\epsilon$?

A trival bound by Markov is 
$$P(X>\varepsilon C)\le \frac{E X}{\epsilon C} = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$$
However, because the variable is bounded by $C^2$, for $\varepsilon\ge C$ we have $P(X>\varepsilon C)=0$. Supposing this value is a continuous w.r.t. $\varepsilon$, it is interesting how does the $1/\varepsilon$ bound switches to to $0$ over the range $[0,C]$.

it is pretty clear that in general settings the worst-case behavior would happen when the distribution of $X$ is bimodal, i.e., a Dirac delta at $X=0$ and another Dirac delta $X=C^2$ with values that satisfy $E X = C$. But because of monotonicity, the variable cannot be bimodal. What is the worst-case scenario in this case?

Comment: By “can we bound [...] regardless of $C$” do you mean find a bound independent of $C$? Because if not, since $f$ is monotonically decreasing on $[0,C^2]$ we have for any $0<x<C^2$ that $f(x)<f(0)$ so that $P(X> (1+\epsilon C)) < f(0)C[C-1-\epsilon]$ (is a trivial bound) right?

Comment: yes that's right, i mean a bound which is not based on $C$.

Comment: @Henry, Yes the conclusion on $C$ is correct. Actually, you can assume it's arbitrarily large if necessary.  
Actually, there is a trivial bound by Markov, which is $P(X>(1+\epsilon)C) \le 1/(1+\epsilon)$, I'm trying to see if monotonicity here could be of help or not

Comment: @Henry I actually suspect that when $\epsilon\gg 1$, the $\mathcal{O}(1/\varepsilon)$-type decay is not tight at all,. The reason is that $P(X>(1+\epsilon)C)=0$ for $\epsilon=C$ which is much less than $\frac{1}{C}$ or $\frac{1}{2C}$.  supposing that $P(X>(1+\epsilon)C)$ is continuous in the range $\varepsilon\in[0,C]$, the question is how fast does the small-$\varepsilon$ regime switch to the large-$\varepsilon$ regime

Comment: @Henry I added these to the post with some minor changes to make the question more clear

Comment: can you explain how the tag "concentration of measure" applies to this post ... not because i think it doesn't but because i want to learn more about the tag

Comment: also, what do you mean by "worst case" ... is there a more quantitative term that captures what you intend here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need $C \ge 2$ for this to work at all with the requirement for a non-negative random variable with a monotonically decreasing density (i.e. a mode at $0$) bounded above by $C^2$ and with a mean of $C$.  Then I think you have

$\mathbb P(X>\varepsilon C) \le \left\{\begin{array}{lrr}
        1, & \text{for }& \varepsilon \leq 0\\
        1- \dfrac\varepsilon 2, & \text{for }& 0 \le \varepsilon \leq 1 \\
        \dfrac{1}{2\varepsilon}, & \text{for }& 1 \le \varepsilon \leq \frac C2 \\
        \dfrac{2(C-\varepsilon)}{C^2}, & \text{for }& \frac C2 \le \varepsilon \leq C \\
        0, & \text{for }& C \le \varepsilon \qquad 
        \end{array}\right.$

and that this is tight if you consider a distribution which for some $0 \lt p \le 1$ has a cumulative distribution function $\mathbb P(X \le x)= (1-p) + x\frac{p^2}{2C}$ when $x \in \left(0,\frac{2C}{p}\right]$.  The optimal values of $p$ seem to be to use $p=1$ when $\varepsilon \leq 1$, $p=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ when $1 \le \varepsilon \leq \frac C2$, and $p=\frac{2}{C}$   when $\frac C2 \le \varepsilon $.